# How can I make an aggregated property support ActiveRecord::Dirty semantics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an aggregated attribute which I want to be able ask about its _changed? ness, etc.

```
composed_of :range,
            :class_name => 'Range',
            :mapping => [ %w(range_begin begin), %w(range_end end)],
            :allow_nil => true
```

If I use the aggregation:

```
foo.range = 1..10
```

This is what I get:

```
foo.range                # => 1..10
foo.range_changed?       # NoMethodError
foo.range_was            # ditto
foo.changed              # ['range_begin', 'range_end']
```

So basically, I'm not getting ActiveRecord::Dirty semanitcs on aggregated attributes.  Is there any way to do that?  I'm not having a lot of luck with alias_attribute_with_dirty, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get ActiveRecord::Dirty semantics because aggregated attributes are not association proxies, being mere wrappers for your actual attributes - that's why you have no access to ActiveRecords goodness through them.

Note, that `foo.range_begin_changed?` *should* work, so you may try to see if you can use `foo.class#method_missing` (e.g. defined in a module to be included) to automatically map `*_was`,  `*_changed?` etc methods to those called on actual attributes of `foo.class`.